Approaching the knowledge of knowing using premises

The only thing(knowledge) that I know is that I don't know anything/I know nothing. (Universal Quant.). Does this mean that I don't even know that I know to begin with?

The only thing(knowledge) that I don't know is that I don't know anything. (Alt: I know everything else except for the fact that I don't know anything). Does that mean I know everything, but I still don't know that I don't know so maybe not "everything" (there exists something I don't know i.e., "the fact that I don't know anything)?

The only thing(knowledge) that I don't know is that I know anything. (I know everything else except the fact that I know anything, even a single thing. So does this mean everything else I know I actually don't know?)


Now I have some knowledge about formal logical proofs but I don't know how to do it for this specific scenario. One thing that I want to make clear is that these statements, I have used and have heard these being used almost colloquially, but I want to see how it would fair when dissecting it; in a formally logical way and further epistemologically.(simultaneously)
Also, are these just oxymoronic statements with no basis for actual philosophical discussion?
Dictionary:

Start selecting a "dictionary": names and predicates to be used. Example: "I do not know anything" is "There is no x such that Know(I,x)" and so on. It is quite easy...

@MauroALLEGRANZA Dictionary - Name: Know/to know - K(x), Predicate: I know - K(I). As for "I don't know anything" ~K(I) with quantifiers attached to it, I will leave that to the responder.

By trying to approach knowledge by using formal logical is like you are trying to win a fight in real life by using the rules of a war game, ex. chess.

IMO you have to make a difference between the act of knowing, using a predicate, and the "object" known. K(i) means that I know (what?) Or that someone knows the I?

@MauroALLEGRANZA Sorry, this was what I was struggling with in the first place. But what I meant to say is that I know one thing (this would be one premise) -> "I don't know anything"(the object) this will be the second.

This is the issue: you want to solve a riddle that is due to ambiguity in natural language. If you formalize it, you have to choose how to "solve" the ambiguity..

@MauroALLEGRANZA Can you elaborate how I could possibly remove the ambiguity, you mentioned the act of knowing, using a predicate and "object". What do you mean by that, because like I mentioned I know the act of knowing is acting on one "thing" and that "thing" is "the fact that I don't know anything".  Does this work?

Maybe a formal analysis of knowlwdge is already available... See Epistemic Logic and Jaakko Hintikka, Knowledge and Belief: An Introduction to the Logic of the Two Notions (1962).

@MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you for the source, I find it very helpful although I couldn't find a section that directly addresses my question I found something similar but nothing similar to all three of my statements.

I guess my whole motivation was to know how do we know what we know (how we know what we know).

Let K(a, P) be the predicate that "a knows that 'P' ", and let i be a constant denoting you (or me, if you don't want to bear the brunt of the paradox :)).
We will need to invoke a standard principle about knowledge:
Factivity of knowledge (FP): "If K(a, P), then P" is a theorem (for any a)
(1): "The only thing that I know is that I don't know anything".
(1) is similar to Knower's paradox, but is not paradoxical when (1) is false.
Let A be the sentence "I don't know anything"
A = ∀P, ¬K(i, P)
(1) says:
K(i, A) ∧ (∀Q, K(i,Q) → Q = A)

Assuming (1) is true, K(i,A), and by (FP), we have that A. By the definition of A, it is the case that ∀P, ¬K(i, P). Plugging in A for P, we have ¬K(i, A), contradiction.
Assuming (1) is false, we have ¬K(i, A) ∨ ¬(∀Q, K(i,Q) → Q = A). Nothing paradoxical here.
Notice that without (FP), we can't really get a contradiction even if (1) is true. If I can know something that is false, then it may as well be the case that A is false and I know it.
(2): "The only thing that I don't know is that I don't know anything."
(2) says:
¬K(i, A) ∧ (∀Q, ¬K(i,Q) → Q = A)

From ∀Q, ¬K(i,Q) → Q = A, we can prove ∀R, ¬(R = A) → K(i,R). So (2) implies that you know everything besides (2). We don't have a contradiction here because when I don't know some proposition P, it could still be true or false. It just so happens that "I don't know anything" is false, because I do know everything else.
(3): The only thing that I don't know is that I know anything.
Let B be "I know anything", B = ∀P, K(i,P)
¬K(i, B) ∧ (∀Q, ¬K(i,Q) → Q = B)

Similarly, we can prove ∀R, ¬(R = B) → K(i,R). All is well here.

+1 Great answer. Do you mind delving into the epistemological value of the statements now that you have shown the logical proof

@Howwhye sorry but I don't know much epistemology (at least I can assert that!)

No problem, what you have answered here is really enough.

Although, I must say that you haven't technically defined Q and it seems like the variables keep changing without warning. I do understand the logic but it gets confusing when you don't define the letter before hand and switch. Can you please clarify?

The variables P and Q (and R) are bound to quantifiers. I used different variables so there's no confusion about which quantifiers they are bound by. We can't really "define" the variables because they are just placeholders for things in the domain.

I didn't mean define as in the variables, I meant to say declare them and what predicate they refer to

ohh, no they aren't predicates, they refer to propositions. So any capital letter you see that doesn't have parenthesis () following it is a proposition (this includes constants like A and B and variables like P, Q, and R). The only relation is the binary relation K. We are technically working within a second order logic to be able to quantify over propositions, but there are ways to get around that which will allow us to work within first order logic (but I will need to add quotations which makes the notation messier)

+1 good work! Compare with Epistemic Logic: K(a, φ) reads “Agent a knows that φ”.

+1 This is instructive.

You ask:

Also, are these just oxymoronic statements with no basis for actual philosophical discussion?

The latter two seem to be exercises in universal and existential quantification, but the first saying is a theme in epistemology. It's about gauging how much one knows relative how much there is to know, and recognizing that the ratio is overwhelmingly in favor of what is not known. It is a reflection to encourage epistemic humility. From the article:

"I know that I know nothing" is a saying derived from Plato's account of the Greek philosopher Socrates: "For I was conscious that I knew practically nothing..." (Plato, Apology 22d, translated by Harold North Fowler, 1966).1 It is also sometimes called the Socratic paradox (emphasis mine)

My guess on the first one starts with breaking it down.

The only thing(knowledge) that I know is that I don't know anything/I know nothing.

1 There exists a unique thing: ∃!Θ
2 I know that thing: Ki(Θ)
3 That thing is "I do not know a thing": Θ≡"I do not know a thing"
4 I do not know a thing: ∀Θ ¬Ki(Θ)
Of course, the paradox seems to reside in the constructions in 2:Ki(Θ) and 4:¬Ki(Θ) since they are contradictions. Today, however, we wisely draw a distinction between an object language and a metalanguage, so that allows us to say that:

The idea in 2 can be read as that we know a distinct proposition. That we do.
The idea in 4 can be read as understanding we know almost nothing relative to all things that are known. Also very true.

The end result is something that sounds like a contradiction, but is not when it is reflected upon. This is called dissolution. If paradox and contradictions interest you, you can read up on paraconsistency (SEP) and dialetheia (SEP), or read into some famous paradoxes in philosophy (SEP).

+1 It's really amazing how you always come in clutch. Thank you so much. But, I have to say you didn't discuss my second and third statements i.e., break down the formal proofs for those as well as their inherent epistemological significance

I'm at work now, maybe later. Take a look at the structure for 1, and see if you can't flex the notation a bit to work for you on 2 and 3.

How is the object and metalanguage distinction being used here? It seems like both senses of Ki(P) is "I know that P"; they both reside in the object language. If the object language is semantically closed with respect to is-known (by me) predicate, then OP's 1 does generate a paradox.
Although there seems to be an easier solution, which is to change 1 to "The only thing that I know is that I don't anything besides this very proposition," and seems to be in line with what someone who asserts 1 would believe.

@confusedcius I'll reread everything, but my line of reasoning: 'I know that P such that P is "I know nothing"' is ' I know that "I know nothing"'. Therefore, the meaning of knowledge about a proposition (KNOW1) is not the same as the knowledge about one's own knowledge (KNOW2), which reveals the claim as a form of equivocation. Because it's an equivocation, it dissolves the notion there is a contradiction in meaning, because KNOW1 and KNOW2 are polysemous. How is this line of reasoning in error?

@confusedcius Perhaps my knowledge of the meta/object language distinction is flawed. If we are discussing our knowledge about a set of propositions, and we have propositions that discuss matters, if the semantics of the logic that we use to discuss the propositions is richer than the semantics of the logic we use within the propositions, then how isn't the richer semantics that describes the constrained semantics a description and therefore above and "meta to" the language used by the propositions?

@confusedcius I'm thinking our differences in interpretation resolves around your imposition of the meaning of KNOW1 on KNOW2 (which to be fair may be the intent of the problem if the OPs problem is an assignment for a logic class), but otherwise isn't internal to the actual sentence itself?

@JD ah I see, I think my understanding of the meta vs object language distinction was too narrow. You are correct that this solution is one such instance, just as the Tarskian solution to the Liar is also such an instance. This solution mirrors the tarskian solution (stratification with infinitely many level of languages) perfectly. Would that be a correct observation?

@confusedcius Okay. I wanted to reflect before I responded, and I'll answer your question, which should exhaust the conversation (though if I'm always willing to engage a fellow thinker so it needn't). First, your answer is the answer the OP was seeking, and using an epistemic logic was the right call. Epistemic logic is a product of Fregean/Tarskian truth-conditional semantics, and all logicians rightfully gravitate towards it, but its not the only metasemantic theory. As a computer scientist (just a well educated software engineer that is) I have a different toolbox informed by cognitive...

semantics and a wider reading of the philosophy of language, one more empirically and pragmatically oriented. So, I think in terms of a post-Montagovian, traditional grammar-oriented formalism. Mine at the moment happens to be type-theoretic semantics which is closely related to the work done in dynamic semantics. Thus my notion of meta/object language is informed by seeing a dynamic semantical context as essentially a domain of discourse which governs the differentiation of the two languages...

So, when one internalizes propositions into a language and uses use-mention notation (which comes in a variety of technical styles beyond quotation marks and is sometimes implicit such as moving from an actual to hypothetical context or a fact-based to fictional context) what one is doing is declaring distinct contexts (Γ1, Γ2, ...) generally using the same natural language as a base...

but natural languages can be constrained or augmented to serve a linguistic function. And functions are pragmatic creatures, so when one comes across oxymorons and paradoxes and antinomies and the like, once can seek a resolution using formal truth-conditional semantics as you have done, or one can look for instances of polysemy and equivocations of contexts. Mathematical logic and truth-conditional semantics is fascinating, but so too are post-Montague grammars that approach it from a more linguistic perspective... so let me try to reiterate my solution in logical notation...

First one differentiates the predicates by context: K_m(I,M) ∈ Γ_m, K_o(I,N) ∈ Γ_o (meta and object). The one asks, which formalisms do I want to apply? For Γ_m, since it takes as objects propositions, we decide epistemic logic prevails. But, applying epistemic logic to both contexts is normative and strictly speaking not necessary. In the case of Socrates' paradox we ask, what was the meaning of the claim about knowing nothing? Was he thinking in terms of epistemic logic? No. He was using rhetoric to cultivate epistemic humility...

Thus, K_o(I,∅) isn't translated as ∀M ¬K_m(I,M), but rather as Ignorant(Thinker). Now instead of K_1(I,∅) ⊥ K_2(I,N) : N!=∅ : K_1, K_2 ∈ Γ_m, we simply accept the coherence of K_m(I,M) ∈ Γ_m, Ignorant(I) ∈ Γ_o since the domains of discourse regarding knowledge about propositions and an appraisal of one's epistemic capacities in relation to those of the collective universe of computation are distinct. And there is how dynamic semantics context applied to two instances of the same token with different types and resolves the paradox from a semantic, rather than syntactic strategy.

@confusedcius my($0.02) If you see any fatal flaws in the thesis, I'd be honored to be humbled. Thanks for the exchange!

I don’t think I understood the linguistics part, but I think I understood what you said when you put it in logical notation. So I’d imagine this solution can be applied to the knower paradox (“this sentence is not known”) in a similar manner: we know_2 that this sentence is not known_1, and these two sense of knowing are in distinct contexts. I related this to Tarksi’s hierarchy, where we start with a base language without the truth predicate, then we construct a meta language with the truth predicate that can only apply to sentences in the base language…

If we allow the truth predicate in the second language to talk about itself, then we get the Liar sentence in the second language, which is precisely what we want to avoid. So we don’t allow that. but to talk about truth in the second language, we add a third language that has a truth predicate that applies to the second language, and so on, continuing infinitely. So we retain most of the expressiveness of natural language because for any sentence on the hierarchy, we can talk about its truth, but no truth predicate can talk about itself. We need to do the same thing here with know predicate

Because supposedly, we should be able to talk about knowing_3 that we know_2 that this sentence is not known_1. And to avoid the 3rd level knower paradox (this sentence is not known_3), we’d need a fourth level, and so on, continuing infinitely. This solution works, it avoids the paradox

Also an unrelated question; as someone also coming from a computer science background, I don’t plan on pursuing further education in philosophy, though I would love to keep up with it, particularly logic. is there any resources or perhaps communities that you find most helpful to allow a non-academic to continue engaging with this? Btw we should probably take this to chat if you want to respond
